# SQL Occurrence Comparison?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image][image]

**Above is a picture of this particular table*

I need to write a query for a database that lists the name of a department for the department that controls the most projects.

In my database, departments are identified by dnums.

So my question is, how can I write something that checks for the greatest occurrence of a Dnum in SQL? Because that's how I will identify the department that controls the most projects.

I've tried several different queries, but none of them work properly.

Could anyone explain a method that could compare occurrences?

Comment: Could you include an example here

Comment: Of my Database? Or Queries I've tried?

Comment: table data with your decided result

Comment: This is what my table looks like:

Comment: Pname | Pnumber | Plocation | Dnum                                                                                    ----------   -----------     -----------       5                                                                             ----------   -----------     -----------        5                                                                            ----------   -----------      -----------        4

Comment: @Gary edit the question please, don´t include it inside the comments

Comment: ugh. formatting got trashed. my apologies. I'll try to find an image to attach instead

Comment: @KevinEsche, my apologies. Just made an edit with a far clearer image. Can I delete comments if this string gets to long?

Comment: You mean Dnum si your department identifier?

Comment: yes it is the identifier

Comment: Do you have a table of your department

Comment: yeah I do I can attach it as well

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server? You tagged both. Then, what is your actual problem? You certainly know that you count in SQL with `COUNT`? And you certainly know you get an aggregation result such as `COUNT(*)` *per* DNum with `GROUP BY DNum`? So where exactly are you stuck? You should always show your query, so we can point you to where you are mistaken or how to proceed.

Comment: This Was my Idea: select Dname
   from department, project
   where Dnum=Dnumber
   group by Dnum
   having count(dnum)

Comment: I got stuck near the end of the query because I can count ALL of them, but I don't know how to compare

Comment: Okay then, MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: I used MySQL for my DB

Comment: That's bad luck ;-) See my answer on this.

Comment: So much discussion- well, I'll add my 2c... see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know already how to count per department:

```
select dnum, count(*) from project group by dnum;
```

In SQL Server it is easy to select the dnum(s) with the maximum occurrences; you order by count descending and take the top row(s) using `TOP() WITH TIES`.

```
select top(1) with ties dnum from project group by dnum order by count(*) desc;
```

(In standard SQL that would be `order by count(*) desc fetch 1 row with ties`).

In standard SQL (and SQL Server) you also have the option of ranking your records per count:

```
select dnum
from (select dnum, rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rnk from project) ranked
where rnk = 1;
```

MySQL doesn't give you any of these options, lacking both a `WITH TIES` clause and analytic functions such as `RANK`.

So in MySQL you would not find the departments with the maximum count in one step, but only the maximum count alone first. You would get the according department(s) only in a second step.

Two approaches here:

```
select count(*) from project group by dnum order by count(*) desc limit 1;
```

or

```
select max(cnt) from (select count(*) as cnt from project group by dnum) counted;
```

Then join the counted departments again:

```
select p.dnum
from
(
  select count(*) as cnt
  from project 
  group by dnum
  order by count(*) desc limit 1
) m
(
  select dnum, count(*) as cnt
  from project 
  group by dnum
) p on p.cnt = m.cnt;
```

The last step is the same in both DBMS:

```
select dname
from departments
where dnumber in (select dnum ...);
```

(Or join the departments table instead, so you can show both name and count.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the COUNT function:

```
SELECT dnum, COUNT(*)
FROM project
GROUP BY dnum
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

If you need the department_name, you'll have to join to your department table (assuming you have one). It could look something like this:

```
SELECT d.dnum, d.name, COUNT(p.pnumber)
FROM department d
INNER JOIN projects p ON d.dnum = p.dnum
GROUP BY d.dnum, d.name
ORDER BY COUNT(p.pnumber)
```

Comment: select Dname
   from department, project
   where Dnum=Dnumber
   group by Dnum
   having count(*);

Comment: this was my original idea, but I know idea how to take it and find the max occurences. Is there a way to compare counts?

Comment: What do you mean by "max occurrences"? The dnum with the highest number for COUNT?

Comment: Actually (sorry it's late), I see the answer to my question is in your answer. Let me try that. Thank you so much for being so willing to help me out

Comment: I'm VERY new to SQL, so I hadn't seen ORDER BY before

Comment: No problem! The order by will hopefully give you what you need. Happy to help.

Comment: By max occurences, I mean the number of times the Dnum appears in the table. If say, 5 appears 3 times in the project table, then it controls the most number of projects

Comment: Still just a tad confused on how to compare things. If say Research controls 3 projects and Administration controls 2, how can I say in SQL who controls more?